# command phasescriptexecution failed with a nonzero exit code react native IOS

Tags: react-native-ios

i am facing PhaseScriptExecution error
when i try to build IOS then project not build this give the following error

the following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/ali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NassauTennisMobileApp-akwowvjtagvlxbalhbsvukoitagy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/NassauTennisMobileApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NassauTennisMobileApp.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh

Answer (score -1):

For me: It seems that react native doesn't like spaces in the directory. I was able to build my ios after removing all of the spaces in my directory.

Potential solution to your problem, didn't fix mine but it might help you: The author suggests there is a mismatch between the node version that you're using and the one that xcode is calling/using. The author provides a way to check the versions installed as well as a way to symlink between the two versions => https://dev.to/glocore/react-native-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-of9